# Can I force unoptimal logical condition checking?

Tags: dart

Is it possble to change the whay the logical or `||` statement is executed in dart.
For example. I have the functions `foo()` and `boo()` which have a return type of `bool`. If i write

```
(foo() || boo()) ? /* A */ : /* B */;
```

and `foo()` returns true `boo()` would not be executed. I would like to be able to change that, but couldn't find a way to do so.

I was surprised to see that this will not help:

```
bool helper = false;
helper = helper || foo();
helper = helper || boo();
(helper) ? /* A */ : /* B */
```

Comment: If you change the helper to `bool helper = foo(); helper = boo() || helper;` then it should work. Which is really just: `var tmp = foo(); ... (boo() || tmp)...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boo()` is only executed when `foo()` returns true, because the result would be false anyway (short-circuit). You have to force explicit execution like:

```
var f = foo();
var b = boo();
(f || b) ? print('false') : print('true');
```

If you want to use it inline you can use a custom method like mentioned by @AlexandreArdhuin or

```
[foo(), boo()].reduce((v1, v2) => v1 || v2)
    ? print('false') : print('true');
```

Try it in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/8b00ee002f6e0f237a57).

Answer (score 3):

non-short-circuit boolean operators is the phrase you are looking for, and it is not possible at the moment, see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/1080

Answer (score 3):

You [can not use `|` in dart](http://dartbug.com/1080) but you can write an helper function like `or` and have a syntax quite close:

```dart
main() {
  if (or([foo(), boo()])) {
    print('ok');
  }
}

bool or(List<bool> values) => values.fold(false, (t, e) => t || e);

bool foo() {
  print("foo");
  return true;
}

bool boo() {
  print("boo");
  return true;
}
```

Try it in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/244da507fdece733a949).